# Let $f, g$ absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ with $f'(x)=g'(x)$ a.e. on $[a,b]$. Prove if $f=g$ at a single point in $[a,b]$ then $f=g$ everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f, g$ absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ with $f'(x)=g'(x)$ a.e. on $[a,b]$. Prove if $f=g$ at a single point in $[a,b]$ then $f=g$ everywhere

This is not homework, this is part of a list of problems that it would be advisable to solve before a general exam. Any suggestion is welcome, I have tackled it on my own but after hours of work I'm blind, I know I'm asking a lazy question but I need to move on, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just use the fact that $f(x)=\int_a^x f'(t)\, dt$.

Comment: I am not sure which theorems you are allowed to use and which are not. But the result is almost trivial from the [*fundamental theorem of calculus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in [a,b]$ we have by absolute continuity that

$$f(x)-f(a) = \int_a^x f'(t)\,dt = \int_a^x g'(t)\,dt = g(x)-g(a).$$

Therefore $f(x)-g(x) = f(a)- g(a)$ for $x\in [a,b].$ Since $f$ and $g$ agree somewhere in $[a,b],$ we have $f(a) = g(a),$ which implies $f=g$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

I'll use the following lines from [Wikipedia, equivalent definitions of absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity):

So, suppose $\exists x^{*} \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x^*) = g(x^*)$. Under this, assume that $\exists x$ such that $f(x)\neq g(x)$. Then,
$$
f(x^*) = f(a) + \int_{\left[a,x^*\right]}f'(t)dt = g(x^*) = g(a)+ \int_{[a,x^*]}g'(t) dt
$$
where both integrals are Lebesgue integrals. Since, $g'=f'$  a.e. on $[a,b]$, the integrals satisfy
$$
\int_{[a,x^*]}f'(t) dt = \int_{[a,x^*]}g'(t) dt.
$$

Hence, $f(a) = g(a)$.

Finally, with this, the hypothesis $f(x) \neq g(x)$ gives us the following contradiction:
$$
f(x) - g(x) = \int_{[a,x]}f'(t)dt - \int_{[a,x]}g'(t) dt \neq 0
$$

as $f'=g'$ a.e. implies $\int_{[a,x]}f'(t)dt - \int_{[a,x]}g'(t) dt = 0$.